# Why is my soldier breathing heavily after running?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I have a S rank Combat Female soldier, I don t remember which mission rewarded me with her, but she don t have anything special beyond S rank and a heavy breathing just after a sprint.

Is it normal? Is it linked with the virus? Or is it just a random characteristic of that soldier?

Comment: I haven't used female soldiers in missions yet, so I can't say directly, but I recently read this post about Amber Fox (the mid-rank female soldier you get from registering the code that came with Ground Zeroes): https://heyitschet.wordpress.com/2015/09/09/metal-gear-phantom-snake-rise-of-the-amber-fox/ and this writer notes that "when she stops running, she sounds like an overweight smoker who started at age 12 trying to catch her breath after a brisk jog". That seems to be evidence that this is common to the female soldier voice clips.

Comment: Well, what is weird is that I when using another female soldier, I don t get that. But the other soldier is A+, so less interesting in term of stats.

Comment: Hmm! I'll have to check the performance of my female soldiers. I only have Amber Fox and one or two others.

Comment: My Amber Fox (a C-rank in combat) also has the heavy breathing.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you've noticed, but Snake also breathes heavily after a sprint, albeit briefly. One would assume that all soldier types breathe heavily just after a sprint, based on that precedent. Knowing Kojima's sense of humor, he likely made the other soldiers breathe more heavily just to make Snake seem more badass.

Comment: Am I wrong? I played the game too, you know. Why the downvotes?

Comment: Probably because your response is based on assumptions and not based on anything concrete (Therefore not an answer but a comment). (I didn't vote by the way.)

Comment: It is concrete, though. Snake also breathes heavily after a sprint. I don't know why you'd assume that the female soldiers' heavy breathing is somehow special; it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: This looks accurate to me. To the best of my understanding, all soldiers (including Snake) have a collection of sounds they use, including one for heavy breathing while/after sprinting. Variations in the breathing are likely just variations in people who contributed the breathing sound to give variety to the characters beyond just having sounds for generic male soldier and generic female soldier

Answer (score 2):

Certain Female soldiers (esp [#31 volunteer](https://unknown321.github.io/mgswaifus/#) [Flaming Buffalo](https://www.reddit.com/r/metalgearsolid/comments/53lrnr/the_definitive_guide_to_getting_your_combat_unit/)) have this characteristic wheezing.

IIRC, I have a random female "Wild Buffalo" with this, too.

Comment: While it does answer the question, your links points to things unrelated and could be seen as publicity